# What is the charge flow between a charged capacitor and an uncharged capacitor connected in series

Tags: circuit-analysis, capacitor, series, discharge, charge

[image: Circuit Diagram]
What will be the charge on both the plated after `bc` is closed? `(Imagine that both the C1=C2=C)`

Comment: Suppose initially there is 1 Coulomb of charge on C1 and 2 Coulombs on C2. How do you think those 3 Coulombs will distribute themselves when the switch is closed?

Comment: @ErikR I think 1.5 Coulomb on each capacitor plate

Comment: That's correct because C1 = C2. If C1 and C2 are not equal the charge distribution will also be unequal as described in Majid's answer.

Comment: btw - C1 and C2 are connected in parallel, not series.

Comment: Please tell me one thing `Q=C/V` is the formula or `Q=CV`?

Comment: Q = CV. One approach is to determine total Q. Then caps in parallel have equivalent capacitance of C=C1+C2. Final voltage V after switch closes is Q/C. Final charge on each cap is V*C1 and V*C2.

Comment: All caps have some resistance, how much energy is lost?

Comment: Conservation of charge AND conservation of energy are both required to be satified. If your final result's energy is not equal to the initial energy, then the solution could be **wrong**!

Comment: Energy is never conserved due to ESR, some is dissipated.

Comment: If this is a homework question, with no other information in the question other than the circuit diagram shown,  the resistance in the circuit is probably zero. inifnite current will flow at the instance of switch closing and who knows what will happen then! This *uncharted* capacitor territory.

Comment: @AJN Redistributing charge like this will necessarially reduce the total energy even in ideal situations. This is because E is proportional to V^2 and V is proportional to q. Charge (q) is fixed and charges will redistribute to the minimum energy configuration. Unless no charge moves you will lose energy. You cant conserve both.

Comment: @Matt exactly. That is why i feel that this is an ill posed question as they do not explicitly show any element which can dissipate the energy. An ESR has to be assumed to be present. Which is not really fair when given as an assignment to a student. Feels like a trick question.

Comment: @AJN No, its not necessary to show a place where energy is dissipated. If concerned you could model the wire resistance then take the limit as it goes to 0, but thats much more work for the same answer. (Since in the ideal case energy dissipated in the wires is something like the integral of infinity^2 × 0 dt, you have to use limits to resolve this integral) (but since the result is the same for any resistance it is a pretty easy limit to evaluate)

Answer (score 0):

Some charge will flow from the charged capacitor to the uncharged capacitor until an equilibrium is reached. At that equilibrium state, both capacitors will have equal voltage (as is the case in parallel connection) and their respective charges will be given by the formula : Q = CV. So Q1 = C1V and Q2 = C2V, where V is same for both, and is given by V = (C1V1 + C2V2)/ (C1+C2). Here V1 and V2 are initial voltages of the respective capacitors.

Comment: What do you mean by `as is the case in parallel connection` ?? And also the formula for charge in a capacitor is `Q= CV` Not `Q = C/V` as much a I know @Majid Ahmad

Comment: What's the reason for accepting this answer which wrongly says Q =  C/V while it's actually C.V ?

Comment: Sorry about all the errors that I did and thanks for the edits. Responding to your question @Souradip Mandal, when capacitors/resistors/inductors are connected in parallel, they have equal voltage. This is a something very basic.